# UIButton and @3x images (using Image Assets)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode7

I've got a problem here and it's easy to explain:

I'm using image assets for a new project being built in Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.1.

I have a bunch of buttons with images set. The buttons are much larger than the images and so they center (as expected) just fine on any @1x or @2x screens.

However, as soon as I build to the 6+ with its @3x resolution, the button instead uses the dimensions larger than the @1x image and the image in the center of the button becomes larger.

So I have an image that's 20x20, 40x40 (for @2x), and 60x60 (@3x).

If I build to an iPhone 6, the image dimensions are indeed 20x20 and the @2x image is used for the double resolution. But if I build to the 6+, the image dimensions are made larger. I don't know exactly how much larger but it's larger than 20x20. This is only happening with UIButton.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I was rendering the images at 4x instead of 3x.